# Convert dictionary to list of float-element

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I want to convert this dictionary to a list of float elements.

I have some code, but I don't know how to achieve this. The `.csv` file I have consists of both number and words. The new dictionary that is created only consists of *some* of the elements from the `.csv` file.

```py
import csv
def load_csv(filename):
    with open (filename, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        result = {}
        for row in reader:
            key = row[1]
            if key in result:
                pass
            result[key] = row[3:]
        lowercase = {k.lower(): v for k, v in result.items()}


    # This last part is just to check which type the elements are
    s = lowercase.values()
    print(type(s))
    for i in lowercase.values():
        print (type(i))
    print(lowercase)

load_csv('CO2Emissions_filtered.csv')
```

Comment: What's an example of the input you have and the output you want?

Comment: why don't you `result[key.lower()] = float(row[3])`? you don't even need the last dict

Comment: @diggusbickus I see now that the code i wrote at first was a bit wrong, " result[key] = row[3]" is supposed to be result[key] = row[3:] (i've edited it now) and when i change that i get "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'". Do you know how to solve that"?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to explain what your input currently looks like and what your desired output should look like.

If I understand the question, you want to create a list of floats from the values in the dictionary?
If so, all you need to do is a simple list comprehension using the values of the dictionary.

```py
float_elements = [float(val) for val in dict.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dict into a list with key and value, this is an option.

```
import csv
def load_csv (filename):
  with open (filename, 'r')as f:
  reader = f.readlines()
  result = []
  for row in enumerate(reader):
      result.append(row)
      print(result)
```